# Odds ratio for two factors

Tags: regression

In logistic regression, is it possible to calculate the odds ratio of two variables? For example, I always see the odds ratio of only one variable being calculated (ex: e^b1) .... but is it technically wrong to do this for more than one variable ex: e^ (b1 + b2) ?

Is this permissible?